FFMPEG conversion from .ts files to .mp4 playback issue
I am converting a bunch (990) of .ts files into an .mp4 video file using ffmpeg.
The resulting .mp4 file will play perfectly fine in vlc, however when I play it in QuickTime on Mac, or more specifically my own video player that uses an AVPlayerView it will play fine for about 10 minutes, then the sound will start to skip, as in every 2 seconds there is a very brief blip/pause. Stopping the video and playing it again from the same point let's it play fine again for another ~10mins.
My initial thought was an issue with my own video app, but QuickTime has the same issue.
I'm combining all the .ts files like this:
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy video.ts

Then I convert it into an .mp4 like this:
ffmpeg -y -i video.ts -acodec copy -vcodec copy video.mp4

Other things I tried
Specifying the video codec:
ffmpeg -i video.ts -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 video.mp4

First converting to .mkv:
ffmpeg -i video.ts -map 0 -c copy output.mkv
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -acodec copy -vcodec copy video.mp4

Convert to m4a:
ffmpeg -i video.ts -vcodec h264 -c:a aac video.mp4

I noticed when I use ffprobe it reports the final video as 29.88 fps but the original .ts is 30 fps. I'm not sure if this is the problem, so I tried forcing the framerate to stay the same:
ffmpeg -i video.ts -acodec copy -filter:v fps=30 video.mp4

None of the above seem to make a difference.
Could there be an issue with how the .ts files are combined? Although the full .ts appears to play ok in QuickTime.
Is there another method I can try to combine them?
Stream details
Original single .ts file:
Input #0, mpegts, from '162.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:05.49, start: 883.612144, bitrate: 873 kb/s
  Program 1 
  Stream #0:0[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s
  Stream #0:1[0x100]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn

Combined .ts file:
Input #0, mpegts, from 'video.ts':
  Duration: 01:30:21.54, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 690 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
  Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn
  Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s

Converted to .mp4:
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf61.1.100
  Duration: 01:30:21.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 616 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 480 kb/s, 29.88 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

Converted with fps=30:
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf61.1.100
  Duration: 01:30:21.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 768 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 632 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
        encoder         : Lavc61.3.100 libx264
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]


playlist.m3u
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:10.00,
segment_1.ts
#EXTINF:10.00,
segment_2.ts

// Rest of your files here

#EXTINF:10.0,
segment_300.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST 

Then run ffmpeg with the .m3u file:
ffmpeg -i playlist.m3u -c copy output.mp4


This works perfect, thank you. Interestingly, the resulting video is 22 seconds shorter than what all the other methods created, so I guess that's what was causing the skipping.
